# Error de "Id already being tracked" actualizando tablas con una relacion de muchos a muchos

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, entity-framework, excepciones

A pesar de revisar ya varios post que hablan sobre este error, sigo sin entender donde estoy metiendo la pata.

Estoy intentando importar desde un archivo excel datos que seran representados en dos tablas y que tienen una relacion de muchos a muchos, el clásico Estudiantes/Cursos:

Models:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class CourseStudent
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

este es mi Context:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    
    public DbSet<Course> Course { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CourseStudent> CourseStudent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasMany(op => op.Courses)
            .WithMany(cp => cp.Students)
            .UsingEntity<CourseStudent>(
                r => r.HasOne(prop => prop.Course)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(prop => prop.CourseId),
                r => r.HasOne(prop => prop.Student)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(prop => prop.StudentId),
                r => { r.HasKey(prop => new { prop.StudentId, prop.CourseId }); }
            );

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<Course> GetCourseAsync(string courseName)
{
    return await context.Course
        .Include(x => x.Students)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Name.Equals(courseName));
}

public async Task<Student> GetStudentAsync(string studentName)
{
    return await context.Student
        .Include(x => x.Courses)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Name.Equals(studentName));
}

public async Task<bool> AddCourseAsync(Course course)
{
    await context.Course.AddAsync(course);
    return await context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
}

public async Task<bool> AddStudentAsync(Student student)
{
    await context.Student.AddAsync(student);
    return await context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
}

public async Task<bool> UpdateStudentAsync(Student student)
{
    return await context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
}
```

Y por último, mi método Import:

```
public async void ImportFileAsync(string excelFile)
{
    // reading the excel file, truncate tables and other stuff
    ....
    
    foreach (IXLRow row in usedRows)
    {
        var studentName = row.Cell(StudentIndex).Value.ToString();
        var courseName = row.Cell(CourseIndex).Value.ToString();

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(studentName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(courseName))
            continue;

        Course course = await sqlDbRepository.GetCourseAsync(courseName);
        if (course == null)
        {
            course = new() { Name = courseName };
            await sqlDbRepository.AddCourseAsync(course);
        }

        Student student = await sqlDbRepository.GetStudentAsync(studentName);
        if (student == null)
        {
            student = new()
            {
                Courses = new() { course },
                Name = studentName
            };
            await sqlDbRepository.AddStudentAsync(student);
        }
        else
        {
            student.Courses.Add(course);
            await sqlDbRepository.UpdateStudentAsync(student);
        }
    }
}
```

utilizando un juego de datos como este (tabla excel):

| Student | Course |
| --- | --- |
| Física | Juan |
| Física | Pepe |
| Química | Juan |
| Química | Pepe |

La primera row se inserta correctamente, y mis tres tablas se actualizan correctamente:

**Student**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Juan |

**Course**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Física |

**CourseStudent**

| CourseId | StudentId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

Pero en cuanto intento actualizar la segunda explota como cafunga en el

`await sqlDbRepository.AddStudentAsync(student);`

Alguien podría darme una luz?